# Database table setup: Multiple tables that serve the same purpose?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to setup a MySQL database for a bugtracker, that's paired with a changelog.

Therefore I essentially have three tables: `product`, `version`, `problem`, `problem_solution`. The reason I splitted problems and their solutions is that I want to be able to provide my users with a set of possible solutions.

Now I want to add attachments to each of these tables and manage them via the database as well. There should be pictures, PDFs, ... for each product, version and possibly for each problem and solution.

Would I rather

- Create 4 attachment-tables (`product_attachments`, `version_attachments`, ...), or
- Create one attachment-table and create a column stating what it is for?

If latter, how should I do it? I want to reference to the specific ID of the product, version, problem or solution using a foreign key. Should I then just create 4 columns, each of them with a foreign key and decide whether it's an attachment for a product, a version, ... depending on which of these columns is not NULL? Wouldn't this make my queries unnecessarily complex?

Answer (score 1):

I say create one table, have its primary key available, and create another table of EAV type for multi-to-multi relation between attachments and other entities, with "value" corresponding to attachment ID, "entity" to foreign ID and "attribute" to a value out of a fixed set of `product, version, problem, solution` in any form you like (1,2,3,4?). This way the attachments will be stored in a table of `id, blob` structure, maybe with corresponding `count` column storing the amount of links in the relation table, so that an orphaned attachment could be detected and removed with ease.

Comment: Is using an EAV model really a better solution than the "classic" relational model in this scenario?